# Does .Net (Specifically the Socket.EndAccept Method) ignore the OS's configured dynamic port range?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, port

So I am trying to resolve an issue for a customer at my work.  The client's setup is that they have 11 pieces of our hardware throughout their city that collect data and then every hour connect to our server application via the cellular network to connect and dump the data.  The server application is just a C#.Net 4.5 windows service that has an async socket server listening on a pre-configured port.  For some reason two weeks ago one of the pieces of hardware stopped being able to connect most of the time.  It would maybe succeed 1 time per day instead of all 24 like it typically had for over a year.  then a week ago another started doing it as well, basically exactly the same.  After further research and logs analysis I noticed that at the time the first system stopped working it's outbound (dynamic port, assigned by the server) switched from "not 1024" to 1024.  Same situation with the second one that stopped working.  However, 3 days ago the first one to stop working all of a sudden started to work again and at the exact same time that it's port switched from 1024 to something else.  the second one is still not working and is still connecting with port 1024.  Strangely I have seen other instances of the hardware at the same client use port 1024 and be successful.  So all I can really say is that every time it is not working it is using port 1024 but not necessarily that it is port 1024 that is the problem.  I also don't understand how both pieces of hardware, which have separate IP's are getting assigned the same dynamic port within seconds of each other.  The server application does nothing to attempt to chose the dynamic port, it just uses the socket that is returned from the call to "Socket.EndAccept Method (IAsyncResult)".  I started trying to reproduce using one of our servers running Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise and the hardware that was connected was assigned port 1024.  This doesn't make any sense to me because the default for this OS should be 49152-65536 and running "netsh int ipv4 show dynamicport tcp" returns "Start Port: 49152 - Number of Ports: 16384".  Also I thought the ports would get assigned "Randomly" not incrementally, but all of my logs show an incremental tendency and I cannot understand why ports 1024 - 1100 are always the ones chosen when the OS should be choosing the outbound port and using the OS version's default range.

I am totally stumped by all of this and TCP networking is not my forte, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929851) is interesting, it mentions port 1025 to be significant.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with the C# language or the .NET Framework.  Find the kind of people that troubleshoot these problems at serverfault.com

Comment: I know that a lot of the things I mentioned don't but my actual question is directly about the .Net framework.

Comment: _"to chose the dynamic port, it just uses the socket that is returned from the call to `Socket.EndAccept`"_ -- that makes no sense. `EndAccept()` has nothing to do with dynamically-assigned port numbers; the socket returned from that method will always have the same local port number as the listening socket (which you state is "pre-configured", which would be typical for a server).

Comment: Most likely you are just dealing with some kind of firewall misconfiguration issue, in which you sometimes get lucky and get a port that's not blocked. But in the highly unlikely event this question is in fact on-topic here, it's useless without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem.

Comment: For the sake of specificity, the inbound port that the server is listening on is 5004. But after the hardware connects it's connected via 5004 as the inbound port and 1024 as the outbound port. I thought that the outbound aka dynamic port is selected inside that method but I could be misunderstanding, if so please enlighten me. Also I will attach a sample when I have the capability.

Comment: _"it's connected via 5004 as the inbound port and 1024 as the outbound port"_ -- that makes no sense. Sockets are full-duplex. There is no "inbound" and "outbound" port, except in the sense of a TCP listening port (which naturally is inbound only). Maybe your _application protocol_ imposes directionality, such that you only receive on one socket and only send on another (why?!), but that's not a socket API thing at all.

Comment: Like I said, it sounds like I am misunderstanding this, but it does sound like what you described is the case, that it's bound to one port for listening and opens the actual connection on another port, I understand that ports can be full duplex, but with multiple pieces of hardware connecting to the same server via the cellular network via different IP addresses, wouldn't that violate the 5 tuple rule for them all to be using the port that the server is listening on for a full duplex TCP connection?

Comment: I have some wireshark captures of the situation, unfortunately I don't have them right now since they're at my computer at work. But in the captures each line references 2 IPs and 2 ports, the IPs are that of t he server and that of the hardware connecting over the cell network.  The ports are 5004 and 1024, or in some cases 1024 - 1100 ish.